# How are PCFGs used in programming language design?

Tags: formal-grammars, programming-languages

I've been reading the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_context-free_grammar) about probabilistic context-free grammars (PCFGs), and they state that

> PCFGs have application in areas as diverse as natural language processing to the study the structure of RNA molecules and **design of programming languages**.

but I'm having a hard time finding examples of their usage in programming language design.
So my question is this, what are the uses of PCFGs in programming language design?

Any examples or references would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :]

Comment: These words were rather unceremoniously added in this edit: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Probabilistic_context-free_grammar&diff=prev&oldid=589872498 without any comment and crucially without any reference, citation, or supporting evidence, by a user who appears to be a biologist by training, not necessarily an expert in programming language design. For what that's worth.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of applications in programming language design, and I am a bit skeptical.  However, PCFGs *are* useful for generating test cases, for program testing.